# Visual Studio Clone from Github & push to VSTS

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, git-fork

Here is the scenario I want to implement.

1. The code of opensource Project-X is maintain by some other party (Party A).
2. We (Party B) clone Project-X from GitHub (release branch)
3. Party B do modifications locally
4. Check-In to VSTS repository.
5. Do the deployments from VSTS to Azure

So, this is like Party-B only read updates from GitHub and push modifications that they do locally to VSTS (not Github). So actual read/write will take place to VSTS. GitHub will be only use to read changes done by 3rd party.

Comment: What do you want to achieve, push changes made by Party B from VSTS git repo to github repo, or get new changes from github repo to VSTS git repo etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this to maintain my theme for my blog. It's maintained by Ghost and I have made modifications. [I've blogged about that](https://jessehouwing.net/ghost-vsts-continuous-delivery-of-customized-themes/).

Basically, the trick is to add both VSTS and GitHub as remotes to your local repository:

```
git remote add github https://github.com/org/project.git
git remote add vsts https://org.visualstudio.com/project/repo.git
```

Then in your local repository, you can easily merge changes from github into your local repository:

```
git checkout vsts/master -B master
git fetch github release
git merge github/release -m "Taking latest changes from Github"
git push vsts
```

This will merge the latest changes into your own project. You may need to resolve conflicts as part of the merge.

This workflow is similar the way you'd resolve a cross repo pull request in GitHub.

Comment: I also think branching strategies should give you a solution. Using pull request to branch(es) with policy to protect them.

Comment: Adding pull requests to this process adds additional security, but doesn't effectively change the underlying flow.