# GIT (TFS) error: Authentication failed on HTTPS push

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

For several days I've been fighting the problem of git authentication (TFS). I use VSTS (git from TFS) and Jenkins. I`ve set proper credentials in jenkins git plugin. The project is successfully cloned during the build, but after push (with the same credentials) I get:

```
fatal: Authentication failed for (url of team project)
```

I`ve also tried push commit from pipeline (without jenkins credentials manager):

```
https://username:password@xxxxx.com/xxxxx/_git/xxxx
```

and with Personal Access Token:

```
https://username:PAT@xxxxx.com/xxxxx/_git/xxxx
```

Unfortunately I also got Authentication failed error.

I checked locally using git bash - cloning and pushing with default git URL (https://username:password.xxxxx.com/xxxxx/_git/xxxx) working fine - but when I set remote to:

```
git remote set origin
     https://username:password@xxxxx.com/xxxxx/_git/xxxx
```

and then I push to

```
git push https://username:password@xxxxx.com/xxxxx/_git/xxxx
```

I get Authentication failed error again.

I have no idea how to fix pushing from Jenkins build. I had two ideas (Jenkins credential manager or authentication by username: password in URL). Unfortunately I can't use SSH.

Has anyone encountered such a problem in the Microsoft product (Vsts git)?

Comment: Are you trying to push source code to azure devops/TFS hosted git repo `https://tfsurl.com/8080/GITAgile/_git/GITAgile` from a Jenkins  CI build?

Comment: Yes. The result is: fatal: Authentication failed for (url of team project).

Answer (score 0):

To narrow down  if the issue related to Azure DevOps server/TFS side or Jenkins, you should first try to make git command works properly with git remote, through git bash.

Did you first `git remote add repourl`. Take a look at this link: [Visual Studio Clone from Github & push to VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51905805/visual-studio-clone-from-github-push-to-vsts)

Besides, since you are using Git with TFS, check if you already turned off Basic Authentication.

> We recommend you keep IIS Basic Authentication turned off at all times
>   when using Azure DevOps Server. Only if necessary should you enable
>   IIS Basic Authentication. When IIS Basic Authentication is enabled on
>   your windows machine, it prevents you from using personal access
>   tokens (PATs) as an authentication mechanism.
>
> If you use Git with IIS Basic Authentication, Git will break because
>   **it requires PATs for user authentication.

More details please take a look at this [official link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/iis-basic-auth?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Yesy, I have  Basic Authentication turned off. I`ve tried clone/push sth with git bash. I`ve added https://username:PAT@xxxxx.com/xxxxx/_git/xxxx as a remote and tried to push on it. The result was the same. Cloning/Pushing to the default repo url https://@xxxxx.com/xxxxx/_git/xxxx - orks locally (probably because I have git bash on Windows and credentials are saved in the credential.helper manager. When I try clone/push with PAT - I get above error